# Как правильно употребить слово?

Tags: этимология, фразеология

Что означает выражение "ё-моё"?

Answer (score 1):

Эвфемизм, заменяющий другое известное выражение на "ё", которое я не могу привести здесь по соображениям скромности. Аналоги: "ёшкин кот", "японский городовой" и многие другие.

**Дополнение**. Мысли по поводу. Я как-то читала книгу В.А.Успенского "Труды по НЕ математике". В одной из статей он обсуждает проблемы обсценной лексики, очень интересно и смешно. В частности, он озадачился таким вопросом: можно ли издать закон, запрещающий употреблять матерные слова? Если да, то надо как-то определить, какие именно слова относятся к матерным, чтобы их запретить. Например - перечислить их все. Но всякий закон, чтобы вступить в силу должен быть опубликован! Такая публикация сама по себе будет противоречить этому же закону! 
Можно, конечно, написать так: "Запрещено употреблять всем известные матерные выражения", но это уж будет верх лицемерия!